Did Superdana manufacture a 66 AC outlet power strip/surge protector?
This January 2023 Reddit post purports to show a power strip with 66 outlets.


Extension Cord 7 in, SUPERDANA Power Strip Surge Protector with 12-14
USB Charging Ports and 66 AC Outlets, 900W/4A, Flat Plug Power Outlet for Home, Office, Dorm, Gaming Room, Fire.

The text already seems fishy as it describes potential places of use as “Home, Office, Dorm, Gaming Room, Fire”.
A quick search of Amazon in the U.S. shows no manufacturer called “SUPERDANA”; but there are many similar power strips being sold by the company “SUPERDANNY” such as this 22 AC outlet strip.
An April 2023 tweet also includes the image.
Was this product being sold?

Obviously a fake but how would you prove it? There are some signs of copy-paste on parts of the image and "900W/4A" does not make any sense, likely copied from a different product.

'"900W/4A" does not make any sense' - It's about right for 220-240V power.  Doesn't work with the US style plug though.

A couple of funny things about the picture: a) it shows 13 USB outlets (the average of "12-14"?); b) it shows 56 outlets, not 66 (which is not divisible by 8, the number of rows)

There's ones along the edges that don't line-up @hdhondt The eye ignores something outside the main pattern too easily.

@hdhondt: actually there are 5x10+2x8=66 AC outlets in the photo. The original 22-outlet thing also had this feature that it had more outlets per row in the inner columns (2x6+2x5).

No, this is a parody image which has been attributed to, and apparently claimed by, Dana Sibera (hence "SUPERDANA"?), who goes by "NanoRaptor" on social media sites and has created many parody images of electronic devices. This article (thanks @Giacomo1968) gives her name and shows examples of others she has created, and this is an archive of links to her work.
A post on Mastodon/fediverse attributes the SUPERDANA image to her, and was boosted by her own account. Discussion in that thread mentions it indeed being a parody of the real products branded as "SUPERDANNY".

Part of this parody which I appreciate is that it doesn't just add silliness to normal things, but instead riffs on silliness we already have in the real world: the SUPERDANNY power strip mentioned is already larger than most people would expect, which can make it appear unsafe, and listings on Amazon often incorporate long lists of keywords in their product names.

That being said, now that the design is out I wouldn't be surprised to see a real version on Aliexpress in a month and in two months on Amazon.
